# Taking the mean of several different lists in one for loop numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have 25 different lists each with name x, followed by a number. For example x1, x2, x3, x4... x25. I wish to take the mean of each list and append these means to a new list. But am running into an error with numpy:
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

```
 meanlist = []
for i in range(1,26):
    curlst = np.array('x' + str(i))
    mean = np.mean(curlst)
    meanlist.append(mean)
```

I am getting the error at the line attempting to take the mean of the current list. 
I am sure this is a simple fix but I was unable to find similar problems when searching online.

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of lists in that form in the first place? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: How about just `meanlist = [np.mean(x) for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24, x25, x25]]`?  (But answer @Sebastian's question first.)

Comment: I'm a fool. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for having variables in the form `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3`, etc. You should instead have a list `xxx_list` which contains all of them. That being said, you could use `eval`:

```
[np.mean(eval("x"+str(i)) for i in range(1,26)]
```

Comment: There's probably a better way to do this but I essentially needed to run a function with different parameters (those being 1 to 25) which returns a list of every output of those parameters (list of size 1000), 25 different parameters. If I were to use one list it would be harder for me to distinguish the expected value of each parameter, unless of course I chose to use positions in the list as my "different lists" Thank you for the help of course though :)